# How to send byte array from server(jetty server) to client(RPI)?

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to send bytes of data from server to client, so i am using the file pointer to point to location the file has read and read set of bytes and send it to client.

Below is server side

```
byte[] b = readByte()// my function which return bytes of Data
ServletOutputStream stream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
stream.flush();
stream.write(b);
stream.flush();
```

Below is client side

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1222/?filePointer=" + fp);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.connect();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
System.out.println("Connection Open");
int pos = 0;
byte[] b = new byte[buffLength];
while (pos != -1) {
    pos = is.read(b, pos, b.length - pos);
}
write2File(b);
```

The above code works for bufferLength of 20Kb, as bufferLength is increased I receive improper values.

Comment: How is the client supposed to know how many bytes are coming?  Flushing the output stream on the server side does not adequately serve this purpose.  The size needs to be explicitly included with the data.  Among the possibilities for that is to precede the data with a byte count (that the client knows to expect), or to mark the end of the data with a delimiter of some kind (that cannot appear in the data, and that the client knows to look for).

Comment: I have set buffLength on both sides so i can read only particular Bytes on line ( i hope that server sending buffLength and client reading buffLength , so no need for explicitly specifying ). Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as you have clarified that the server and client have a common agreement on the number of bytes to transfer, represented by `bufferLength`, you are right that they do not need to to exchange that length.

But the client does need to *use* that length correctly.  Your problem is in the client's read loop:

> ```
> int pos = 0;
> byte[] b = new byte[buffLength];
> while (pos != -1) {
>     pos = is.read(b, pos, b.length - pos);
> }
> ```

There is one definite and one potential major problem with that:

1. Your receiving code does not populate the destination array correctly on the third and subsequent iterations of the loop (when that many iterations are performed), because `pos` records only the number of bytes received in the most recent previous `read()`.  You need to use the aggregate number of bytes read in *all* previous reads into the array up to that point to determine the offset and number of bytes to attempt to read.
2. `InputStream.read()` will return `-1` only at the end of the *stream*, which will not normally occur on a network stream until the far end is closed.  If the server does not close the connection (at least the output side) from its end after writing the array, then the client will hang trying to read it.  In particular, it will go into a tight loop if `pos` is equal to `b.length`, so that the number of bytes requested is 0.

Comment: Ya the pos points to last read, so i forgot to add the pos of 1st iteration on 3rd iteration. Thanks @John Bollinger